# Does Python 2.7 implement PEP 370 on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos

According to [PEP 370](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/), Python on Mac OS X will look for `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`

Unfortunately my Python (installed from python.org) only looks in `~/Library/...` What's up with Python? Is the PEP out-of-date, or are there different Python versions for OS X that look in the other directory?

Comment: How did you install it? Also, there is this note: "*On Mac OS X Python uses `~/.local` directory as well. [12] Framework builds of Python include `~/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages` as an additional search path.*"

Comment: I installed from a .dmg from python.org, after discovering the "limitations" of default OSX Python (such as the missing source code to the standard library).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently for Python OS X framework builds for Python 2.7 and 3.2, the user site-packages directory is searched for in `~/Library/Python` rather than `~/.local`.  There have been disagreements among the Python core developers on this variance from PEP 370.  See http://bugs.python.org/issue8084 for some of the discussion about this still open issue.